# Scrolling a layout when the keyboard appears( Chat app with recycler view)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scroll

I want to make chat page like Telegram, when keyboard appears layout scrolling up but only body not app bar. Also after keyboard appears, recycler view must be scrollable and when keyboard disappear layout must scroll down. Sorry my poor English. Thanks.

I tried scroll view and

```
scrollLastPosition = myLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
scrollFirstPosition = myLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()


private fun layoutChanger() {
    binding.messageRecycler.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, bottom,
                                                        _, _, _, oldBottom ->

        if (scrollLastPosition == messageArrayList.size - 1 && bottom < oldBottom) {
            binding.messageRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(messageArrayList.size - 1)
        } else if (scrollLastPosition < messageArrayList.size - 1 && bottom != oldBottom) {
            if (bottom > oldBottom) {
                binding.messageRecycler.postDelayed({
                    binding.messageRecycler.scrollToPosition(scrollFirstPosition)
                }, 0)
            }
            binding.messageRecycler.postDelayed({
                binding.messageRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(scrollLastPosition)
            }, 10)         

//binding.messageRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(scrollLastPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    tools:context=".view.MessageActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messageRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="640dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/messageRecycler"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/writeMessage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:hint="@string/type_here"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="5dp"
                tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp">

            </EditText>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sendImage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/send"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo">

            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

but nothing is work like Telegram.In this layout it works but after keyboard appears, when I scroll recycler view edit text also scolling down and disappear, I want that edit text doesn't move.

Comment: Can you show How you used the `ScrollView` in the `XML` file?

Comment: I added my scroll view layout

Comment: Don't use `NestedScrollView` instead use `ScrollView` as the root layout. `NestedScrollView` is used when the layout is inside another with this it will not scroll when opening the keyboard.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, can you give me some example that it works like Telegram, when keyboard appears, layout move up, but when I scroll recycler after layout move up, edit text doesn't move.

Answer (score 0):

In the layout file, based on your requirements, using NestedScrollView tag is counter-productive, removing that layout and directly making ConstraintLayout the root view should solve your problem.

Comment: I want that when keyboard appear, layout scroll up, if I remove scroll view, how it will be?

Comment: As per your description, you want something that works like telegram, that when the keyboard opens, your textView should be visible, right? this behaviour can be achieved without the ScrollView and RecyclerView is by itself a child of NestedScrollView, so if you are concerned about the messages scrolling they will work even without the NestedScrollView, just try it.

Comment: Can you give me some example please

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove the NestedScrollView so that your layout looks something like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messageRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="640dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/messageRecycler"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/writeMessage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:hint="@string/type_here"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="5dp"
                tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp">

            </EditText>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sendImage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/send"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo">

            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: But I want that When keyboard appears , bottom of layout move up to top of keyboard. I mean when keyboard appears layout scrolling up with it.

Comment: You mean to say that you want layout to be at the latest message when keyboard opens, right?

Comment: I tried, Layout scroll up but some recycler view items stay under keyboard and edit text